# Python - Parsing Json file and getting multiple values from dictionaries in list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

json file and I successfully parsed it as you can see below. What I want is Get the Id Of ['Users'] and get ['Photos'] ['Url'] part for the related Id.

My .json output

```
{u'Success': True,
u'Total': 172159,
u'Users': [{u'AboutMe': u'U\xe7mak i\xe7in ku\u015f olmak gerekmiyor, k\xfc\xe7\xfck sevin\xe7ler olsun yeter.',
         u'Age': 34,
         u'Education': None,
         u'EyeColor': u'Mavi',
         u'Gender': 2,
         u'HairColor': u'A\xe7\u0131k kahve',
         u'Height': 183,
         u'Id': u'19185978',
         u'IsHot': False,
         u'IsOnline': True,
         u'Job': u'Serbest meslek',
         u'JobId': None,
         u'LastActivityDate': u'2018-03-07T03:43:50.53855Z',
         u'Location': u'\u0130zmir - Merkez',
         u'LookingFor': None,
         u'MaritalStatus': u'Single',
         u'MaritalStatusId': None,
         u'Photo': None,
         u'Photos': [{u'CreateDate': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00',
                      u'Id': None,
                      u'PhotoName': None,
                      u'State': None,
                      u'Url': u'https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/a2f/a2fe1237-e0e1-4456-bd7b-b1d55bc8f00e.jpg.jpg'},
                     {u'CreateDate': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00',
                      u'Id': None,
                      u'PhotoName': None,
                      u'State': None,
                      u'Url': u'https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/87f/87fba6a5-8555-4b53-968b-678f832fd28f.jpg.jpg'},
                     {u'CreateDate': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00',
                      u'Id': None,
                      u'PhotoName': None,
                      u'State': None,
                      u'Url': u'https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/18d/18d3d6bc-97ec-49c3-80d4-57d4e58d020f.jpg.jpg'},
                     {u'CreateDate': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00',
                      u'Id': None,
                      u'PhotoName': None,
                      u'State': None,
                      u'Url': u'https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/eba/eba25a06-4168-49cf-b0cb-e501d0efb965.jpg.jpg'}],
         u'RelationshipType': u'E-Posta Arkada\u015fl\u0131\u011f\u0131, , , ',
         u'StatusMessage': u'Siz istiyorsunuz ki her \u015fey benim istedi\u011fim gibi olsun, herkes pe\u015fimden ko\u015fsun. Ama her zaman \xf6yle olmuyor.',
         u'TownName': None,
         u'Username': u'45ahmet35',
         u'Weight': 85,
         u'Zodiac': u'Ko\xe7',
         u'ZodiacId': None},
        {u'AboutMe': None,
         u'Age': 42,
         u'Education': None,
         u'EyeColor': u'Kahverengi',
         u'Gender': 2,
         u'HairColor': u'K\u0131rla\u015fm\u0131\u015f',
         u'Height': 175,
         u'Id': u'19274893',
         u'IsHot': False,
         u'IsOnline': True,
         u'Job': u'',
         u'JobId': None,
         u'LastActivityDate': u'2018-03-07T03:43:24.555Z',
         u'Location': u'\u0130zmir - Alia\u011fa',
         u'LookingFor': None,
         u'MaritalStatus': u'Single',
         u'MaritalStatusId': None,
         u'Photo': None,
         u'Photos': [{u'CreateDate': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00',
                      u'Id': None,
                      u'PhotoName': None,
                      u'State': None,
                      u'Url': u'https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/bf0/bf0fbad6-076a-4924-b496-5385044c08bc.jpg.jpg'},
                     {u'CreateDate': u'0001-01-01T00:00:00',
                      u'Id': None,
                      u'PhotoName': None,
                      u'State': None,
                      u'Url': u'https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/998/99893a8e-5342-441f-bd83-82fa20bdb27a.jpg.jpg'},
                     ],
         u'RelationshipType': u'',
         u'StatusMessage': u'Yok ',
         u'TownName': None,
         u'Username': u'kaya3510',
         u'Weight': 80,
         u'Zodiac': u'Ko\xe7',
         u'ZodiacId': None},
```

And My Python Code

```
import json

json_obj = json.load(open("13.json"))

for i in json_obj['Users']:
    print i['Id']
    print i['Photos']['Url']
```

And the Error I get.

19185978
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/siberAlem/parser.py", line 7, in 
    print i['Photos']['Url']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the error hints, `i['Photos']` is a list (of dictionaries), not a dictionary. In your sample data, there are multiple photos associated with both users.

Comment: `i['Photos']` is a *list*.  So you can ask for `i['Photos'][0]['Url']` for example.

Comment: Thank you larsks and hoyland. Larsks I tried your solution but that does not work. There are multiple Url values and I want to get all of them for the related Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
for i in json_obj['Users']:
    print i["Id"]
    for j in i["Photos"]:
        print j["Url"]
```

**Output:**

```
19185978
https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/a2f/a2fe1237-e0e1-4456-bd7b-b1d55bc8f00e.jpg.jpg
https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/87f/87fba6a5-8555-4b53-968b-678f832fd28f.jpg.jpg
https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/18d/18d3d6bc-97ec-49c3-80d4-57d4e58d020f.jpg.jpg
https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/eba/eba25a06-4168-49cf-b0cb-e501d0efb965.jpg.jpg
19274893
https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/bf0/bf0fbad6-076a-4924-b496-5385044c08bc.jpg.jpg
https://diymyqt2ncnnc.cloudfront.net/s3/traktorumnetphotos/998/99893a8e-5342-441f-bd83-82fa20bdb27a.jpg.jpg
```

Comment: You are Welcome :)